# How to add double quotes character at the end and starting of a word with + symbol before and end at Boolean character?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, keyword

I have an input text form, which takes text character as an input from frontend user.

Example :- Word1 OR word2 OR word 3

and want to convert the string as below example ,

```
"Word1"+OR+"word2"+OR+"word 3"
```

I wonder if it is possible with PHP to do that with either using `preg_replace()` or `str_replace`.

I have tried with passing values in multiple variable using below code, but not getting specific ans.

```
`Input from user`$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
`replacing OR with +`$keywords1 = str_ireplace (' OR ', '+OR+', $keywords);
`start with "`$keywords2 = str_ireplace ('', '"', $keywords1);
```

Please suggest...

Comment: `$keywords1 = '"' . str_ireplace (' OR ', '"+OR+"', $keywords) . '"';` presuming that format is always correct.  I would rather have each keyword as its own input then glue them together with `or` and quote each term.

Comment: I hope it's an Interesting Ans , can you please elaborate more. anyways having multiple keyword input is not possible as There is only one text input area.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't use `preg_replace()` or `str_replace()` for this. Instead try to isolate the keywords from the input-string and then build the desired string yourself.

```php
    $input = 'Word1 OR word2 OR word 3';
    // split input-string into separated keywords:
    $keywords = explode(' OR ', $input);
    // build desired string from keywords:
    $result = '';
    foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
        if ($key > 0) {
            $result .= '+OR+';
        }
        $result .= '"'.$keyword.'"';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Input string
$input = 'Word1 OR word2 OR word 3';

// exploding the string with the keyword then glue the array with expected string
$output = '"'. implode('"+OR+"',explode(' OR ', $input)) .'"';

//printing the output
echo $output;
```